# How can I get dag's planned date?

Tags: airflow

I have a dag that runs an SQL script. So I need to get the date and time when tha dag starts, not the sql script.
I think that TS is what I need, but I'm not shure
[image: ts]

Answer (score 0):

You right, as a jinja template

{{ ds }} - The DAG run’s logical date as YYYY-MM-DD for example: 2023-01-01

{{ ts }} - The DAG run’s logical date as YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss, for example: 2023-01-01T00:00:00+00:00

You can use it in your sql as follow :

```
sql_task = SQLOperator(
    task_id='sql_task',
    name="Aaa",
    sql="test.sql",
    dag=dag)
```

in the file test.sql you can write :

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date > {{ ts }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at this documentation, and look at data_interval_start and data_interval_end.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html

Because of how airflow looks at scheduling, data_interval_start is the scheduled start time of the previous run and data_interval_end is the scheduled start time of the current run.